# Easy SSL server for testing

Tags: apache, networking, ssl

I'm new to the world of networking but I'm working on creating an application that will make an SSL connection to a server. Right now the server is not yet setup but I'd like to begin testing on my application I'm building.

Is there an easy way that I can set up a local Apache server and configure it for SSL?

I'm new to networking so be gentle with me.

Edit:
I'm looking more for how to set up the server functionality. I can set up a VM but how do I make it so it accepts incoming socket connections?

Comment: Have you've seen my comments on [this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81421/having-trouble-selected-a-question-as-answered)  I want to get to the bottom of your issue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care about the content returned by the server, I'd suggest `openssl s_server -www`.  You'll need a certificate, but Dave G's answer describes how to do that (s_server will need to know where the cert is also, but `openssl s_server help` will show you the appropriate flags).

Comment: i keep trying to accept this as the answer but when i click the checkmark its not letting me? any ideas? Im in IE8

Comment: I don't know, I've never asked a question, so I've never seen the interface.  Nor do I use IE8.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which platform you on the tools may already be at your disposal.

this is how to create a "self-signed" certificate

http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html

You will get security warnings but you can establish and utilize an SSL connection.

Comment: Hi Dave G, are there any other website(s) on the creation of "self-signed" certificate?

Comment: I can provide a Gist later today with more information